# Função jQuery de ocultar elementos

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma janela que abre ao clicar em um elemento, blz. Mas como posso fazer para, ao clickar FORA dessa janela, a mesma se fecha?

Comment: Consegui pessoal. Eu só precisava saber como eu pudesse varrer todo meu DOM atras de umas classe e exibi-la/oculta-la.

Comment: Sugiro postar sua resposta abaixo, como resposta mesmo, para que possa ajudar a outras pessoas com o mesmo problema. Se quiser, pode inclusive marcar sua própria resposta como aceita. Para detalhes, ver http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Answer (score 4):

Trate isso num ancestral do elemento que quer esconder:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    // verifique se o clique veio de dentro da sua janela.
    // para isso use e.target (a origem do clique).
    // se não tiver vindo da sua janela, feche a janela.
    // exemplo:
    if(!$('#janela').contains(e.target)) {
        $('#janela').close()
    }
});
```

Comment: Só pra contextualizar ao tópico, com a jQuery seria através de [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que deva ter uma espécie de máscara por trás desse seu conteúdo, correto?

Faz algo do gênero:

```
$("#mascara").click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".sua-tela").fadeOut(function(){
         $(this).hide();
         $("#mascara").hide();
    });
});
```